# Create String with <<""//?? characters Android java

Tags: java, android, string

how can I create a String of characters like

```
String Header = "<div class="tutorial hide alert alert-info req_student">";
```

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: a variable name should start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mask the quotes. This is the solution of the problem from your comment:

```
String header = "<div class=\"tutorial hide alert alert-info req_student\">";
```

Comment: String header = "<div class="tutorial hide alert alert-info req_student">"; is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you should have a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html
It contains the escape characters for java